# python errors on sourcing devel/setup.zsh

Tags: ros, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I source devel/setup.zsh in a catkin_tools workspace while using zsh I get python errors on Bionic using Melodic:

```
% source devel/setup.zsh
  File "<string>", line 1
    from __future__ import print_function
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<string>", line 1
    from __future__ import print_function
^
```

Has anyone else seen this?  Do you have any idea how to troubleshoot this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368945/python-errors-on-sourcing-devel/setup.zsh/) by [tyler-picknik](https://answers.ros.org/users/48265/tyler-picknik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2021-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was cause by issues in my python enviroment.  Closing as this is not an issue with zsh.

---

Originally posted by [tyler-picknik](https://answers.ros.org/users/48265/tyler-picknik/) with karma: 241 on 2021-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-01-05**:
What was the issue?

**Comment by [tyler-picknik](https://answers.ros.org/users/48265/tyler-picknik/) on 2021-01-06**:
It had to do with some bug in colorized cat that uses some python package I installed with pip.  I debugged this by using `set -x` and found it complaining about that library.